# lifetime of functools lru_cache?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lru

I have a flask app running and I'm using it to route various requests over a socket client with various ports. The different ports point to different windows services that I've built using `pyinstaller`.

Each windows service is responsible for consuming a list of arguments and returning a result based on some machine learning models that are unpickled and living in memory inside the service.

I wanted to speed up calls to each service that have identical arguments using `lru_cache` from `functools`, and I am considering putting this decorator on each of the flask routes, to prevent a call to the service.

Does anyone know how long the cache lasts? Does it only exist for the lifetime of a single call stack (using the cache for any calls that are part of this stack like rescursive function)? Or does the cache live on as long as the machine runs?

I know that I need to set the maxsize to utilize the LRU part of the cache, and I know the args that come into the decorated function must be hashable.

Comment: It will be there as long as your program is running.

Comment: Let's say, in scope of your Flask app - you'll have that cache until API request is handled (emitting response)

Comment: Exactly @Poojan this a decorator so it modifies function at declaration so as long as that is called and in namespace (not overwritten, deleted w/ del, etc.) the cache will exist. It is not externally stored cache it is tied to function declaration.

Comment: The cache is a basic dictionary (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py line 519) inside the closure. It lives as long as the decorated function lives.

Comment: If you don't want it to last so long in memory (or want it to persist between sessions) I would recommend implementing your own version and saving it to a a json file. ru_cache is just a dictionary with a max size which maps arguments to an output (so it will always return the same output given the same arguments). You could even make your own decorator to replace lru_cache.

Comment: @RobertGuggenberger by "lives" does that mean if two users from two machines are hitting the API endpoint that both will be able to use the same cache? Or each user will have his own cache?

Comment: I have no clue about Flask and can't answer this. The cache is (unless you write your own implementation)  living only in a single process. Different machines, different caches. Unless the cache lives in the common endpoint, that is.